# npsb; character is causing issues in nuxt3 production server

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, netlify, nuxt3, nitro

while posting a html encoded text to the server, the server side code works fine on the dev environment but when I publish it on a netlify server, the same request returns a 500 error and the server side request log middleware only detects a post request with no body.

server/api/handlePost.post.ts

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { rawLog } = getQuery(event);
  if (rawLog != null) {
    const myRawLog = JSON.parse(rawLog as string) as rawLogArticle;
    //post it to the server...
    return { statusCode: 200, statusMessage: "Success" };
  } else {
    return { statusCode: 500, statusMessage: "SERVER ISSUE" };
  }
```

pages/post/write.vue

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
    if (body.length > 0 && _title.length > 0) {
        const { data: response } = await useFetch('/api/handlePost', {
            method: "post",
            query: {
                rawLog: JSON.stringify(newLogContent)
            }
        })
        if (response.value?.statusCode == 200) {
            await navigateTo("/")
        } else {
            console.error("something went wrong")
        }
</script>
```

for the post body I am using tinyMCE text editor's html content. If the post body includes any `double enter` or `space at the end of a sentence` then the server throws the 500 error. But the chrome network tab shows the request sent did contain the post body.

Manually removing the `npsb;` character from the request's body completes the request without any issues.

Comment: a pretty easy way to deal with it is to use encodeURIComponent in the server-side return

Comment: should i move that comment to the answer to help others in the future?

Comment: yeah, you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a pretty easy way to deal with it is to use `encodeURIComponent` in the server-side return